# Repeat previous label and increment count on non-label lines

Tags: bash, shell, unix, bioinformatics

I have the following string that contain the gene names and exon location.

```
gene1
250405..250551
251490..251884
195620..195641
154254..155469
156319..156548
gene2
171224..171481
403914..403970
147436..147627
149077..149157
11635..12021
gene3
107657..107844
105642..106214
103531..103691
407044..407435
405691..405843
```

I want to write a script that will list all the gene names and the location the output should look like 
that:

```
gene1_exon1 250405..250551
gene1_exon2 251490..251884
geneN_exonN X..Y
```

Any ideas how I can do that?

I have tried the following script

```sh
grep [a-z] temp3 > names
cat names |
while read line; do
  cat temp3 |
  while read position; do
    if [ "$line" != "$position" ] ; then
      echo "$line" ${position} >> names_and_positions
    else
      break
    fi
  done
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pull out the gene name and repeat it before each exon line.

```
awk '!/^[0-9]+\.\.[0-9]+$/ { gene=$1; i=1; next }
    { print gene "_exon" i++, $0 }' input >output
```

On lines which don't look like exon lines, capture the first token as the gene name, and start counting exon lines at 1. On other lines (i.e. exon lines) print the line with the captured string and the exon line number prepended, and increment the number.

This obviously hinges on getting the regex right. If your exon information could contain whitespace around it, or other variations, you'll need to tweak the regex accordingly.

Comment: thank you! how do I add the the exon number next to every gene name ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that requirement. See update now. Your example looks like you need to pick apart the exon lines and repeat the second number, is that a typo? I have not attempted to do that because the requirement is unclear.

Comment: I believe this answer now does what you ask. Demo: https://ideone.com/2g4wKm